# Can I use Settlers of Catan (older edition) with Catan: Explorers and Pirates (2015 ed.)?

Tags: catan

I have an older version of *The Settlers of Catan* (part number 483), and an older version of *The Cities and Knights of Catan* (part number 494), which were purchased sometime around the late 1990s.

I recently purchased *Catan: Explorers and Pirates*, but the game box says "You must have *The Settlers of Catan* (MFG3061) in order to use this game expansion".

Can I use this newer expansion of Catan with my older versions of the base game and expansion?

Comment: What version/language are you talking about? The answer might differ depending on whether you're using Mayfair, or 999 Games.

Comment: Good point!  This is an American english edition (as far as I can tell), published by Mayfair Games.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Aside from some slightly different artwork and renaming of soldiers to knights, the only difference is that the newer edition comes with a frame that has the ports printed on it. You don't need the frame, so you just play without it.

Comment: Although, if you want the frame (which might be important if you want to get the 5-6 player expansion sets and/or Seafarers), there is a "Pre-2007 adaptor kit" (http://www.catan.com/board-games/settlers-catan/settlers-catan-pre-2007-adapter-kit) you can buy that includes the frame and a few other bits and pieces.